# Split dataframe by sequence of times

Tags: r

```
> head(data,25)
  Z     Time
1   682 14:33:40
2    -2 14:33:40
3  -172 14:33:40
4  -300 14:33:40
5  -331 14:33:40
6  -172 14:33:40
7   414 14:33:41
8  1028 14:33:41
9   871 14:33:41
10  407 14:33:41
11 -215 14:33:41
12 -527 14:33:41
13 -134 14:33:41
14  -77 14:33:41
15 -165 14:33:41
16  473 14:33:41
17 1089 14:33:41
18  808 14:33:41
19  -31 14:33:42
20 -488 14:33:42
21 -408 14:33:42
22 -268 14:33:42
23 -172 14:33:42
24  -79 14:33:42
25  310 14:33:42

df_list <- split(data, as.factor(data$Time))
 for (i in seq_along(df_list)) {
 filename = paste(i, ".csv")
  write.csv(df_list[[i]], filename)
}
```

I have used this code to create .csv files for every second of data (data$Time). My data starts at 14:33:40 and ends at 14:38:40 (5 minutes). This code works nicely and gives me 301 files for starting at 13:33:40 (6 lines of data) and working through 13:33:41 (12 lines of data), 13:33:42 (12 lines of data), etc. Now what I want to do, and cannot work out how to do it, is to create a .csv file for every 2 seconds of consecutive data. So the first .csv would be for 13:33:40 & 13:33:41, the second .csv would be for 13:33:42 & 13:33:43 etc. I have tried to find solutions to use the split function in sequence (for every 2 seconds) or to paste the data frames (currently split by every second) in sequence (by 2) but am stuck. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think the simplest way to do it is to create another column that groups seconds 40 and 41 together as 1, 42 and 43 together as 2, etc. and then use your function as it is : `df_list <- split(data, as.factor(data$NewColumn))`. My question is, do you have all seconds in your dataset or you might have some seconds missing? Eg. 13:33:55 could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Time` column has all possible values you can get and that they are ordered, you can use the following approach.
I've created my own simple example:

```
dt = read.table(text = 
                  "  Z     Time
                1   682 14:33:40
                2    -2 14:33:40
                3   414 14:33:41
                4  1028 14:33:41
                5   871 14:33:42
                6   407 14:33:42
                7  -215 14:33:43
                8  -527 14:33:43", header=T)

dt

#      Z     Time
# 1  682 14:33:40
# 2   -2 14:33:40
# 3  414 14:33:41
# 4 1028 14:33:41
# 5  871 14:33:42
# 6  407 14:33:42
# 7 -215 14:33:43
# 8 -527 14:33:43


# add a time id column
dt$Time_id = as.numeric(dt$Time)

dt

#      Z     Time Time_id
# 1  682 14:33:40       1
# 2   -2 14:33:40       1
# 3  414 14:33:41       2
# 4 1028 14:33:41       2
# 5  871 14:33:42       3
# 6  407 14:33:42       3
# 7 -215 14:33:43       4
# 8 -527 14:33:43       4


# flag every 2 values (as you want to group 2 consecutive values each time)
breaks = seq(min(dt$Time_id),max(dt$Time_id), 2)

# look up table to help you with grouping Time values
dt2 = data.frame(Time_id = unique(dt$Time_id))
dt2$flag = ifelse(dt2$Time_id %in% breaks, 1, 0)
dt2$group = cumsum(dt2$flag)

dt2

#   Time_id flag group
# 1       1    1     1
# 2       2    0     1
# 3       3    1     2
# 4       4    0     2


# join grouping info
dt3 = merge(dt,dt2,by="Time_id")

dt3

#   Time_id    Z     Time flag group
# 1       1  682 14:33:40    1     1
# 2       1   -2 14:33:40    1     1
# 3       2  414 14:33:41    0     1
# 4       2 1028 14:33:41    0     1
# 5       3  871 14:33:42    1     2
# 6       3  407 14:33:42    1     2
# 7       4 -215 14:33:43    0     2
# 8       4 -527 14:33:43    0     2


df_list <- split(dt3, as.factor(dt3$group))
for (i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  filename = paste(i, ".csv")
  write.csv(df_list[[i]], filename)
}
```

Let me know if it works for you, if you spot any mistakes, etc.

Comment: Perfect AntoniosK! Thank you very much.